# Bloquear upload de imagens .gif renomeadas com .jpg ou .png no PHP

Tags: php, mime-type

Possuo um sistema de uploads onde o usuário pode fazer upload somente de imagens com extensão .jpg ou .png. Segue parte do código:

```
$imagemNomeAntes = $_FILES["the_image"]["name"];
$imagemNomeAntesExt = basename($imagemNomeAntes);
$imagemNomeExt = pathinfo($imagemNomeAntesExt, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$permitidasExt = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

if(!in_array($imagemNomeExt, $permitidasExt)) {
    echo "Somente imagens com extensão jpg, jpeg ou png são aceitas!";
} else {
    $imagemNomeTmp = $_FILES["the_image"]["tmp_name"];
    $imagemNomeDir = "../photos";

    $imagemNomeEnd = md5($imagemNomeTmp).$imagemNomeExt;
    move_uploaded_file($imagemNomeTmp, ($imagemNomeDir.$imagemNomeEnd));

    imagedestroy($imagemNomeTmp);
}
```

O sistema funciona perfeitamente, porém, se eu for em uma imagem com extensão .gif e renomeá-la para .jpg ou .png o upload acontece e a imagem fica animada. Como posso me prevenir disso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teste da seguinte forma (presente na documentação do PHP)

```
<?php
if (exif_imagetype('image.gif') != IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    echo 'Imagem não é um gif';
}
?>
```

Link para documentação: [Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

Comment: Perfeito! Não havia achado essa função, muito obrigado!